# How to add Authorization header with Retrofit2 + RxJava

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to perform request using Retrofit2 and RxJava

```
public static Observable<Post> getPostsAround(Location location, int offset, int limit) {
    if(api==null) {
        new RestService();  //initialize API in constructor
    }
    return api.getPostsAround(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),offset,limit)
            .flatMapIterable(posts -> posts);   //transform Observable<List<Post>> to Observable<Post> which emits posts onNext
}
```

I tried @Headers("Authorization: code) annotation, but I don't know how to change "code" in runtime.

Comment: What you mean by how to change "code" in runtime. You can add Interceptors to Okhttp and use as client of Retrofit.

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz I mean access token of OAuth 2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found an answer:
A request Header can be updated dynamically using the @Header annotation. A corresponding parameter must be provided to the @Header. If the value is null, the header will be omitted. Otherwise, toString will be called on the value, and the result used.

```
@GET("user")
Call<User> getUser(@Header("Authorization") String authorization)
```